# Unit test methods that the output is the input of another

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I always try to stick to one assertion per test but sometimes I'm having troubles in doing so.

For example.

Say I've written a cryptographic class that encrypt and decrypts strings.

```
public class CryptoDummy
{
    public string Decrypt(string value)
    {
    }

    public string Encrypt(string value)
    {
    }
}
```

How would I create my unit test if the decryption is depended upon the output of the encryption ?

Most of my tests if not all up until now are composed of one method call per test and one assertion per test.

So to the point, is it fine to have multiple calls per test and assert the final results made by the method I called last ?

```
public class CryptoDummyTest
{
    private static CryptoDummy _cryptoDummy;

    // Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        _cryptoDummy = new CryptoDummy();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Encrypt_should_return_ciphered_64string_when_passing_a_plaintext_value()
    {
        const string PLAINTEXT_VALUE = "anonymous@provider.com";

        string cipheredString = _cryptoDummy.Encrypt(PLAINTEXT_VALUE);

        Assert.IsTrue(cipheredString != PLAINTEXT_VALUE);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Decrypt_should_return_plaintext_when_passing_a_ciphered_value()
    {
        const string PLAINTEXT_VALUE = "anonymous@provider.com";

        string cipheredString = _cryptoDummy.Encrypt(PLAINTEXT_VALUE);

        string plaintextString = _cryptoDummy.Decrypt(cipheredString);

        Assert.IsTrue(plaintextString == PLAINTEXT_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an article written by Marc Clifton (one among my favourites) on Unit Testing patterns [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/autp5.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I already read that and purchased the book the Art of Unit Testing long time ago. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldnt have one test depending upon another.  The best way to do this would be to output the encrypted text somewhere and save it.  Then on the decrypt text test you could start with an encrypted text and test you decrypt it correctly.  If you use the same encryption key (which is fine for testing) the encrypted string will always be the same.  So change your second unit test to something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Decrypt_should_return_plaintext_when_passing_a_ciphered_value()
{

    const string PLAINTEXT_VALUE = "anonymous@provider.com";

    string cipheredString = "sjkalsdfjasdljs"; // ciphered value captured

    string plaintextString = _cryptoDummy.Decrypt(cipheredString);

    Assert.IsTrue(plaintextString == PLAINTEXT_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the cipheredString is invalid and so it will always fail.

Comment: I can't even have a constant because the algorithm results a different value each time for the same input.

Comment: I dont see how this is possible unless you use a different encryption key each time?  If you do use a different key each time I'd suggest using the same key every time in your test so you can use a constant to store the encrypted data

Comment: It's possible, there are other approaches to produce different output for the same input other than using a different key such as producing redundancy in the output, different strategy based on the length of the input etc.

However I actually agree with you, I can see how each of these turns into an individual test case.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds strange to me. My opinion of unit testing is, that a unit test will test one special situation with a definite set of data provided. If one test depends on the result of another test, the result is not deterministic. The second thing is, that you can not be asured of the order the tests are executed!

Comment: My tests are completely isolated, the assumption I had is that you shouldn't call multiple methods in the same test method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so religious to say that you can have only one assert per test. If your result to test for example contains some kind of tree structure, you'll have to assert that every stage in the tree is correct, thous leading to multiple asserts, cause it makes (in my eyes) no sense to write for every step a single test.

Also in your given example i can't see that your last test depends on any other test. It simply calls the unit under test two times and indeed you are not really interested on how it encrypt and decrypt the data. All you are interested in, is that it works. So for that kind your tests your tests are absolutely okay.

If you need to test the algorithm used for decryption and encryption you'll have to make two tests and compare the results with some pre-defined constants to make sure that nobody is going to change the algorithm used.

Comment: Thank you, that's really close to what I'm experiencing.

Comment: So far the one assert per test guideline is really working for me, the only thing I have problem with is multiple calls in the same test which you already clarified, now it makes more sense.